# How to end my dependency on .NET?

Tags: python, ruby

I have been developing Windows GUI applications since many years and jumped into .NET in early 2005. .NET is a undoubtedly a remarkable platform and I am still using it, but with a variety of technologies out there, I don't want to remain dedicated to this camp. I want to learn new languages with which I can develop GUI applications.

I am learning Ruby and just installed Python. I read about WxRuby, a framework for developing Windows GUI app. in Ruby. I am searching for a similar framework for Python.

Apart from that I want to know which language is more suitable for a production-level GUI app. I doubt that Ruby is more focused on Web platform with it's glamor, Ruby on Rails.

I know that I may not get those rich .NET classes and that impressive Visual Studio IDE, but still I want to follow the road less traveled. I don't want to go with IronPython and IronRuby, however sometime later, I may dip hands to explore them.

Comment: Real shame that Microsoft decided to just randomly ditch IronPython and IronRuby. I don't think they really understand what kind of disturbing message they sent out to the industry/community in doing so.

Comment: @Rei I don't know what you mean by "ditching" IronPython, but the project seems very much alive, they even released a beta yesterday.

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka - IronPython 2.7 was released on March 21, 2011, just about 2 months ago. IronRuby was released just weeks before that, on March 13, 2011. I see no indications that either has been ditched by Microsoft since then.

Comment: @Mahmoud They stopped spending money on it; they're just letting the community run it now. The lead developer, Jim Hugunin, could no longer work on it from Microsoft, so naturally, he left the company as well: http://hugunin.net/microsoft_farewell.html

Comment: @Thomas: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Microsoft-withdraws-from-IronPython-and-IronRuby-development-1123566.html

Comment: That's not "ditched". It's just not officially backed by Microsoft anymore. The projects still exist and are viable solutions for running Ruby and Python on the .NET framework.

Comment: @Thomas It's still ditched. Just because I ditch my girlfriend doesn't mean she no longer exists or is no longer viable... whatever the latter might mean.

Comment: @Rei, as far as you're concerned, she no longer exists :) Ditched is a one-way ticket to that singles bar where you can hang out with MSDOS, FoxPro, VB6, Silverlight, Flight Sim, IronPython and IronRuby and tell tales of how much love you got in the old days.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Ahh, I miss my PocketPC, back in 2001 when it was just as programmable as Android, had proper multitasking, copy&paste, Unicode, USB host ports, SD ports, CF ports, IR ports, Bluetooth and everything. Now WinMo7 is just as locked down as iPhone was 2 years ago. Where have you gone, PocketPC? Why don't you check your email anymore? Did you change your phone number? :(

Comment: Do you want to stay on Windows or turn to another platform?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check Qt.

it's arguably as rich as .NET, and the IDE (QtCreator) is simple yet pretty powerful.  Of course, it's better used on the native C++, but the Python binding is kept complete and up to date.

On top of it, it's really crossplatform, and that includes mobile platforms now too :-)

Comment: It's hard to call Qt a native C++ system given that it needs a separate compiler before building with it. It's not a bad system though.

Comment: not at all, its 'native' as "compiles straight to machine language, no bytecode/VM/JIT there", also as: "no platform emulation layer, the resultant code is OS-specific".  the `moc` precompiler is nothing more than some syntax sugar to make simpler-looking code in some specific corners (mostly signal-handling); it fits the compile chain in roughly the same place as the C preprocessor.  It's mostly a historical artifact of the API stabilization before certain C++ features had stabilized across compilers

Comment: To be fair, moc does add dynamism that C++ lacks even these days.

Answer (score 6):

Well, wxRuby is just a Ruby binding for [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), an awesome cross-platform GUI toolkit.  There is a similar binding for Python called wxPython, as well as [bindings for many other languages.](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/General_Information)

Comment: The widgets are there but how seamless they integrate with the core language? How active is the community support?

Comment: @RPK - You'll have a fairly small community using any given GUI toolkit with either Python or Ruby. wxPython community is bigger than Ruby though; Ruby's community is dominated by Rails now but Python has more apparent diversity.

Comment: @Jeremy Ruby's community isn't dominated by Rails but it gives the perception that it is, which is a shame.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if your question is limited to determining if Ruby or Python is better or if you're asking which other languages you might want to learn to develop Windows GUI apps in general. I'm assuming the latter.

There are also Java, Delphi, or native Win32 programming. Any of those are suitable for developing GUI apps on Windows. Native Win32 code can (must?) still be written through Visual Studio, but there's no .NET dependency.

Comment: +1 for Delphi.  Build fast, native 32-bit Windows apps without the baggage of .NET.  64-bit version probably coming sometime in 2011.

Comment: @Anna, @tcrosley: I guess Delphi is taking its last breath? Java GUIs are very slow.

Comment: Java GUI's are slow ?  Where is that proved ?

Comment: Native Win32?  Why don't you be merciful and suggest COBOL instead?

Comment: @Tim Williscroft - SWT is fast but most Swing apps are somewhat-to-very sluggish. Its so evident I can't even imagine needing to prove it.

Comment: @David Thornley: I agree that it's not a great/easy to use option, but it does fit the question.

Comment: @Jeremy I bow to your superior knowledge. I'm so embarassed, I've been doing it wrong for years but now I know.

Comment: Native win32 is fine. Not great for quick development, but it's not grievously hard.

Comment: @Tim: I once used a Java IDE few years back. That IDE also incorporated Intelli-Sense similar to that of Microsoft. That time it was new. I remember, when I used to type . (period), nothing happened instantaneously. Until I moved typing ahead just to see that the DropDown menu has opened and I had to keep pressing the left arrow key or use the mouse to reach soon.

Comment: @RPK: I'd hardly say Delphi is "taking its last breath."  It's been on quite the resurgence over the last couple years.

Comment: @Mason: Langpop and Tiobe don't seem to agree. http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/paperinfo/tpci/Delphi.html, http://langpop.com/timeline.html.

Comment: @Jerry: Since when did anyone believe that those were reliable indicators of anything meaningful?

Comment: @Mason: While I'm sure they have a large margin of error, at least they have *some* basis. I'd tend to trust langpop.com considerably more, simply because their basis is published and reproducible. What basis do you have to support your claim of a resurgence?

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 and JavaScript.

I wish I were kidding, [but I'm not](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/06/html5-centric-windows-8-leaves-microsoft-developers-horrified.ars).

Scary to think that no one had this answer half a year ago.

Sad...

Comment: A year or so ago, I commented on Programmers that Microsoft threw VB6 out with the bathwater and that they could do the same with .NET. Somebody responded to me and wrote that MS would never ditch .NET. Well, surprise, surprise! That is why I rather stick with the freedom software and open source communities. If .NET was open source, MS's behaviour would not have mattered that much, because the community could have taken the framework forward.

Comment: Mono has largely caught up. The problem is that the stigma and politics around it make it impossible for other companies to adopt it comfortably. The same story applies to Java, which *is* open source, with Sun trying to sue Google. The difference is that Google didn't expect Sun to sue them. Everyone expects Microsoft to sue them, and so even though they've vowed not to, people avoid .NET/Mono/ECMA C#. Really, this isn't about open source vs. anything; it's about MS having completely lost its head. Almost all software run the risk of its main contributors going crazy or bored, open or not.

Comment: +1 because it's great to be able to port HTML5 and JS straight from the browser into a native desktop application. Now we have web, mobile (using [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)) and windows 8 all under one open source platform!

Comment: The end of the article you linked to suggests that MS *isn't* going to abandon their huge developer base and/or make them all code in HTML5+JS, and that this is more of a PR gaff than anything else.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock it's just microsoft expanding the tools you can use without it deprecating or dropping support for any existing tools. It's a great way to pull in more developers into the microsoft eco system.

Comment: +1, HTML5 is the future of GUI work (even if you don't like the idea). Just put all your 'real' code in the back-end server process and call it from your shiny web GUI. Or any other GUI for that matter. Don't write all your code in JS, connect to the server using websockets or ajax if you have to.

Comment: @Scott @Raynos The thing is, they haven't announced anything in regards to programming the new Win8 UI via Silverlight or C# or anything, and they're being totally mum about it. That's extremely worrying.

Comment: +1 Im currently working on a project that uses ExtJS to create a GUI-like web-based user interface, and some of the advanced features we already have in this app go beyond what you typically see in a nativ GUI app.

Comment: They didn't directly toss out .NET. There is a new framework for Metro apps on windows 8 and those run on .NET. Not the exact same libraries but it's much of what you know and love with different namespaces. I hate random spurious rumors...Silverlight isn't dead, WPF isn't dead, .Net isn't dead...yet.

Comment: @Rig This wasn't a "rumor" when I posted it. It was a frustrating lack of communication on Microsoft's part, and it lasted for *months*.

Comment: You sir, are correct. I completely glossed on the posting date and details were a little skimpy at the time. Still, it was more fear and panic in the masses than any remote indication these technologies were dead.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that the hard-core non-microsoft non-apple people are command-line driven, and GUI design is fairly useless there. They will, to some extent, compromise and make GUIs in HTML, to be consumed by browsers, but that's for their clients, not for themselves.

If you with to stay in the GUI world, I suppose you might want to look at Apple or stay with .NET on Windows.

Makes sense?

HTH

Comment: This isn't strictly true. In the *nix world, we have and use GUIs quite extensively.

Comment: @Christopher: I know and absolutely aware of it. Take for instance, Oracle. They came out with HTML GUI, which is very slow. I am not looking only negatives, probably Oracle can be managed via command-line very well.

Comment: @RPK:  IIRC, Oracle 9i had a wonderful administration tool, which was a GUI desktop app.  I much preferred it to command-line administration.  Oracle 10g implemented that as a web page, which wasn't nearly as nice.

Comment: GTK is pretty popular on Linux desktops, and there are other GUI toolkits. I don't think its common at all to run a desktop without a GUI even if you use terminal for a lot of tasks; though *nix servers you usually would do everything through a command line.

Comment: +1 because I resemble that remark. Typically, GUI programming I do is web-app related. I do make a conscious effort to put that design degree to work by making it intuitive, simple and obvious, but my own computing experience is something like 80% Emacs, 15% browser, 6% other (with a 1% margin of error).

Comment: I said hard-core

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend Java in your situation.

Reasons:

- If you know .NET, you'll be relatively comfortable with Java (C# was largely inspired by Java and many of the conventions and even library names are very similar)
- Java has some impressive GUI capabilities (even if they are not so widely acknowldged). The best cross-platform GUI toolkits are in my opinion Swing (which is totally cross-platform, with a consistent look and feel) and SWT (which also harnesses native components, as used by e.g. Eclipse). JavaFX 2.0 also looks promising for the future.
- There are plenty of "GUI builder" type tools for both (generally available as IDE plug-ins for e.g. Netbeans or Eclipse)
- It's probably a matter of personal preference but I'd argue that Netbeans or Eclipse are, overall , better IDEs than Visual Studio, and certainly more capable than you see for any other languages or platforms.
- The Java platform/ecosystem is a great place to be in general - huge variety of libraries and tools, particularly if you like open source.

Alternatively, you could try one of the new innovative JVM languages like Scala or Clojure if you are feeling adventurous.....

Comment: Also Java developers tend to be more up to speed on the proper way to write software, while many more .NET guys just sling code without applying design patterns, SOLID, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Python works fine for GUI. You can have a look at PyQt, PyGTK, WxPython etc. Those are actively used for GUI development (in Linux) and said to be cross-platform.

Answer (score -4):

Look into other programming languages that work with the .Net runtime, like IronRuby and IronPython. Next, check out the [mono project](http://www.monoproject.org).

These steps will get you out of your .Net comfort zone and developing on Linux. From there, it's a small leap to full-on UNIX-style development.

Comment: -1 because he states in the question "I don't want to go with IronPython and IronRuby"